# Incorrect username/password causes confusing popup in the iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, ios-app

When you choose to login using Stack Exchange - if you type a wrong password the message that pops up is confusing.

It says

> "Error - Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging back in"

Really this should say "Wrong password!" because I spent 15 minutes thinking it was a problem with the app when actually it was a problem with my thumbs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in an upcoming build. In many cases the API doesn't return human readable responses and we have some fallbacks.  This was not one of those cases.