# Not Able to Login to Stack Exchange iOS App : iOS

Tags: bug, login, ios-app

I am not able to Login to Stack Exchange iOS Application  Using my Gmail Account.

EveryTime I login Using Gmail

Login to Gmail >> It asks for Permission >> Accept Permission >> Then Error Message

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe you're still using an old version? See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231317/incorrect-username-password-causes-confusing-popup-in-the-ios-app).

Comment: I am using the latest version of app

Comment: And you can see your emails fine on the mobile device?

Comment: Yes I can see my email from My logged in account

Comment: OK, so it is probably a bug in the app itself, hopefully a dev will see this soon and take a look.

Comment: We've been investigating this and have found some backend issues when connecting to google APIs. We hope to make that process more reliable. Stay tuned.

Comment: Finally able to login after deleting app and redownloading multiple times